# IllegalStateException calling MediaPlayer.reset()

Tags: android, media-player

The documentation for the Android `MediaPlayer` shows that there are no invalid states for the `reset()` call: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States (the invalid states are listed as {}, or "none.").

However, I have seen an `IllegalStateException` thrown while calling `reset()`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1061)
at com.example.android.player.AsyncPlayer$AsyncHandler.handleMessage(AsyncPlayer.java:654)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: Hm, it looked like I was confusing the `MediaPlayer` with another subject. Sorry for confusion. :)

Answer (score 30):

Hard to say without seeing your code but I think you may be calling reset() after you call release() ?

The documentation states

> When a MediaPlayer object is just created using new or after reset() is called, it is in the Idle state; and after release() is called, it is in the End state. Between these two states is the life cycle of the MediaPlayer object.

You may be calling reset outside of the valid life cycle.

Comment: Yes, calling reset() after release() will throw an illegalstateexception

Answer (score 9):

I ran into your issue, Skyler.

You are correct. The documentation shows no invalid states for `mediaPlayer.reset()`, but that isn't the first inaccuracy in the documentation.

What I noticed is that the list of VALID states doesn't say "Any"; it lists every specific state except for two: Preparing and End.

I experimented, but could not cause `IllegalStateException` to be thrown in my attempts to call `release()` while the `MediaPlayer` is hopefully in the *PREPARING* state (using `prepareAsync()`). I won't guarantee it doesn't happen, but I couldn't make it happen. What I did see in that instance were the following log messages:

```
04-11 11:41:54.740: E/MediaPlayer(4930): error (1, -2147483648)
04-11 11:41:54.748: E/MediaPlayer(4930): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Yes, both error messages appear, one right after the other--one with lowercase "error" and one with uppercase "Error," but no exception is thrown.

However, if I call `reset()` after `release()` then I get the error:

```
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.helloandroid/com.android.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at com.android.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity.crashMediaPlayer(HelloAndroidActivity.java:423)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at com.android.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity.onCreate(HelloAndroidActivity.java:87)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     ... 11 more
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1112)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at com.android.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity.crashMediaPlayer(HelloAndroidActivity.java:421)
04-11 11:45:05.232: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     ... 14 more
```

So, The Modern Ink's guess was correct. `MediaPlayer.reset()` throws `IllegalStateException` in the *END* state (which occurs after `release()` is called).

In my case, I discovered I was calling `release()` on `onPause()`, but did nothing to initialize the MediaPlayer again in `onResume()`. Hence, it was in the *END* state when I called `reset()`.

Per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html,

> Once the MediaPlayer object is in the End state, it can no longer be
> used and there is no way to bring it back to any other state.

That means you need to create the MediaPlayer all over again, starting with `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()` or one of the `mediaPlayer.onCreate()` methods. Or be careful about when you call `release()`.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the documentation for the Android `MediaPlayer` is not right about no invalid state for `reset()`. Below's what happen when I experienced it:

In my `PlayerActivity.java` code, I set my `MediaPlayer` as static so that I can use it in my home `activity`:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {
....

public static MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Mediaplayer
    if(mp == null) {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    ....
}
/**
 * Function to play a song
 * @param songIndex - index of song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        if(mUpdateTimeTask != null)
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        mp.reset();
            // the song path is get from internet
    mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
    mp.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
...
}
```

In my home `activity`, I release the player before closing the app:

```
public class TuoiTreAppActivity extends TabActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        if(PlayerActivity.mp != null) {
        PlayerActivity.mp.release();
        }   
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    ...

}
```

So, when I launch the app for the first time and start playing a song. The `reset()` function runs well without error. But when I hit the back `button` to close the app and launch it for the second time, the `IllegalStateException` occurs when passing the `reset()` function.

I also discovered the cause when debugging. As the first time running the app, the player is null so it is initialized in the `onCreate()` function of `PlayerActivity.java`. But the player is not release itself to `null` after the app was closed. So it is not initialized again when re-opening for the second time. That's the reason why `IllegalStateException` occurs when passing `reset()` function. So, to solve this problem, I have to set the player to `null` before closing the app:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    if(PlayerActivity.mp != null) {
        PlayerActivity.mp.release();
        // Set the MediaPlayer to null to avoid IlLegalStateException 
            // when call mp.reset() after launching the app again
        PlayerActivity.mp = null;
    }

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways this can happen:

1. As mentioned before if you `reset` after `release`, you will get an error this is because `release` will dispose of system resources and thus `reset` is an invalid command.
2. If you try to use your `mediaPlayer` object after `release` you will also get an exception. This is because you need to recreate the object and request system resources again.

The right order to get rid of your media player is to release it, and set it to null. This order is **important** as you will have memory leaks otherwise.

Here is a quick example:

```
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
```

Then when your user presses a button, say `play`, you will have to recreate the mediaplayer:

```
public void createMediaPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(callbackDelegate);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(callbackDelegate);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```