# VideoView: IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer.getVideoWidth

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-videoview

I have a fragment that contains a `VideoView` and a playlist of videos. It allows the user to click the videos in the playlist to swap the content of the `VideoView`. It also allows the user seek around each of the videos. It is not feasible to post the entire code here, but I am trying to narrow the issue down so that I can add a sample.

I am finding that if I rapidly change the source of the `VideoView` and seek in the `VideoView`, I am getting an `IllegalStateException`:

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fe8b0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.VideoView$2.onPrepared(VideoView.java:346)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2048)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see there is no reference to any of my code. If I perform the same actions slowly, I don't seem to have the same issue. From reading questions like:

[IllegalStateException calling MediaPlayer.reset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599376/illegalstateexception-calling-mediaplayer-reset)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States

I assume I am performing an action when the player is in an invalid state, but I don't know what that action is. I have a `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener` set on the `VideoView`, but I don't see any errors in the logs. I don't call `reset` or `release` on the `VideoView` at any point.

I initialise the player with:

```
localPlayerVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.player)
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
mediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mediaController.setAnchorView(localPlayerVideoView);
localPlayerVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
localPlayerVideoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
localPlayerVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(localOnPreparedListener);
localPlayerVideoView.setOnErrorListener(localOnErrorListener);
localPlayerVideoView.setOnInfoListener(localOnInfoListener);
localPlayerVideoView.requestFocus();
```

On prepared:

```
localPlayerVideoView.seekTo(time);
localPlayerVideoView.start();
```

Swapping videos:

```
localPlayerVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(null);
localPlayerVideoView.setPlayPauseListener(null);
localPlayerVideoView.suspend();
localPlayerVideoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
localPlayerVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(localOnPreparedListener);
localPlayerVideoView.setPlayPauseListener(localPlayPauseListener);
localPlayerVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Seek in video:

```
localPlayerVideoView.seekTo(time);
localPlayerVideoView.pause();
```

Just before the crash happens I have logged that these are the `VideoView` functions I call:

```
setOnPreparedListener(null)                                                 
setPlayPauseListener(null)                                                  
suspend                                                                     
setVideoPath                                                                
setOnPreparedListener                                                       
setPlayPauseListener                                                        
requestFocus                                                                
onPrepared                                                                  
onPlaying                                                                   
getCurrentPosition                                                              
onPlaying                                                                   
getCurrentPosition                                                              
getCurrentPosition                                                              
onInfo: what: 3                                                             
canPause                                                                    
pause                                                                       
setOnPreparedListener(null)                                                 
setPlayPauseListener(null)                                                  
suspend                                                                     
setVideoPath                                                                
setOnPreparedListener                                                       
setPlayPauseListener                                                        
requestFocus                                                                
onPrepared                                                                  
onPlaying                                                                   
getCurrentPosition                                                              
canPause                                                                    
pause                                                                       
canPause                                                                    
pause                                                                       
setOnPreparedListener(null)                                                 
setPlayPauseListener(null)                                                  
suspend                                                                     
setVideoPath                                                                
setOnPreparedListener                                                       
setPlayPauseListener                                                        
requestFocus
```

How might I track down this error?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. (Nexus 5x, Android 6.0)

Comment: same here.. did you find the reason?